# When to use after triggers

Tags: trigger

When to use after triggers? I came to know that we use after triggers when depending upon the id of a record, if we are modifying fields of another record. But what is my about means in flow of execution the id will be created after commit. If it is case what is id we are working with in after triggers?

Answer (score 4):

There are two phases to changing data in the database that are important to your question:

1. Write to the database, or "save"
2. Tell the database that the write is permanent, or "commit"

The first one happens at the "mid-way" point in the transaction. The data goes into different tables, Ids and automatic field values get generated (CreatedBy/Date, LastModifiedBy/Date, etc.).

This first phase is important as it allows the application to interact with this new data in the state that it should be in, provided all else goes ok.

But between the *write* and the *commit* there is a lot of other stuff that can take place: trigger, workflow, process builder, roll-up summaries, assignment rules, auto-response rules, and more all have the potential to fail and cause us to not want to actually complete the action of writing to the database.

> Side note: a delete is actually just a special database write, too, as it is setting a hidden field value called `isDeleted`.

All this mirrors classic relational database transactional processing, only much of it is pushed into the application tier in our case. And the typical Salesforce transaction is arguably much more complex than a plain-old database transaction.

Finally...when to use *after*.

My recommendation is pretty much in all cases except when you want to set a value into the record that is about to be saved. There will be times when you want to capture something about the transaction in the before state and then act upon that information in after.

An incomplete list of when I use the `after` state:

- Apex managed sharing
- Validation
- Generating other related data
- Sending email response
- Posting to chatter
- Making an async callout

> Note 2: I have disagreed with some on validation in past discussions...but since the transaction will still roll-back on `after`, I prefer to validate in the after phase in order to let declarative validation rules work first. Before triggers fire before custom validation rules, as you can read in the [order of execution docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Comment: A blog post also suggesting benefits for using the after trigger [Where to place Validation code in an Apex Trigger?](http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/04/19/considerations-placing-validation-code-in-an-apex-triggers/).

Comment: Validation can be done before or after-- it's really a matter of system design. While placing code validation in after triggers lets custom validation rules go first, and also allows us to guarantee that other triggers won't change the value on us, it does have the downside of longer transaction times when allOrNone is set to false and an error is recorded-- the trigger logic has to do more work before it fails (so, it's fail slow instead of fail fast).

Comment: I see your point about fail fast and before trigger. I find quite often I suggest validation in the `after` phase and it didn't even occur to people.